# How to use generic type and union types in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a class, and when I initialize it, I pass in a value, or an object about the value

for example

```
new Field<string>('test')
new Field<string>({value: 'test', inactive: 'preview'})
```

but `state.value` is error. (Property 'value' does not exist on type 'FieldState'.
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'T'.ts(2339))

```
interface BoxedValue<T> {
  value: T 
  inactive: 'disabled'| 'preview'| 'hidden'
}

type FieldState<T> = BoxedValue<T> | T

class Field<T> {
  value: T
  _pendingValue: T

  constructor(state: FieldState<T>) {
    if(typeof state === 'object') {
      this.value = this._pendingValue = state.value
    } else {
      this.value = this._pendingValue = state
    }
  }
}
```

thank your solution,I amend the code, but I have a new problem Now.

```
class Field<T> {
  value: T
  _pendingValue: T

  constructor(state: FieldState<T>) {
    if(this._isBoxedValue(state)) {
      this.value = this._pendingValue = state.value // Property 'value' does not exist on type 'FieldState<T>'.Property 'value' does not exist on type 'T'.
    } else {
      this.value = this._pendingValue = state
      // Type 'FieldState<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      // T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'FieldState<T>'.
     // Type 'BoxedValue<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
     // 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'BoxedValue<T>'
    }
  }
  _isBoxedValue(state: FieldState<T>): boolean{
    return typeof state === 'object' && state !== null &&
      Object.keys(state).length === 2 && 'value' in state && 'inactive' in state;
  }
}
```

Why do I make a mistake when I put the judgment condition in the isboxedvalue function, but not in the constructor?

Comment: Can you try logging `state` in the constructor so that we better know what is going on?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [in](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) operator. Using `typeof state ==='object'` can only guarantee that `state` is of `object` type(if the value of `state` is `null`, it's a `object` type as well), but cannot guarantee that it has a `value` property.

> The in operator also acts as a narrowing expression for types.

```
interface BoxedValue<T> {
  value: T 
  inactive: 'disabled'| 'preview'| 'hidden'
}

type FieldState<T> = BoxedValue<T> | T

class Field<T> {
  value: T
  _pendingValue: T

  constructor(state: FieldState<T>) {
    if('value' in state) {
      this.value = this._pendingValue = state.value
    } else {
      this.value = this._pendingValue = state
    }
  }
}
```

Updated:

You should use [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html?#user-defined-type-guards) for `_isBoxedValue` method. The return type `state is BoxedValue<T>` is a type predicate, NOT `boolean`.

E.g.

```
interface BoxedValue<T> {
  value: T 
  inactive: 'disabled'| 'preview'| 'hidden'
}

type FieldState<T> = BoxedValue<T> | T

class Field<T> {
  value: T
  _pendingValue: T

  constructor(state: FieldState<T>) {
    if(this._isBoxedValue(state)) {
      this.value = this._pendingValue = state.value;
    } else {
      this.value = this._pendingValue = state;
    }
  }
  _isBoxedValue(state: FieldState<T>): state is BoxedValue<T>{
    return typeof state === 'object' && state !== null &&
      Object.keys(state).length === 2 && 'value' in state && 'inactive' in state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I have a new problem

Comment: @杨帝武 You should ask a new question instead of changing the original question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know now

Comment: @杨帝武 Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Hi, the problem is nothing that doesn't happen to everybody. Your `typeof state === "object"` is a test for BoxedValue but there's a little mistake: T can also be an object.

### Solution 1

- add one more test

```js
interface BoxedValue<T> {
    value: T;
    inactive: 'disabled' | 'preview' | 'hidden';
}

type FieldState<T> = BoxedValue<T> | T;

class Field<T> {
    value: T;
    _pendingValue: T;

    constructor(state: FieldState<T>) {
        if (typeof state === 'object' && "value" in state) {
            this.value = this._pendingValue = state.value;
        } else {
            this.value = this._pendingValue = state;
        }
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

- specify the type of T

```js
interface BoxedValue<T> {
    value: T;
    inactive: 'disabled' | 'preview' | 'hidden';
}

type FieldState<T> = BoxedValue<T> | T;

class Field<T extends (string | number /* or your type */)> {
    value: T;
    _pendingValue: T;

    constructor(state: FieldState<T>) {
        if (typeof state === 'object') {
            this.value = this._pendingValue = state.value;
        } else {
            this.value = this._pendingValue = state;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't determine its type. but Thank you for your solution, but I have a new problem.